# Passing data from main application view to some subviews

Tags: backbone.js

Please consider following Backbone application structure:

```
AppView
    Subview
        FirstSubviewInQuestion
    Subview
        Subview
            SecondSubviewInQuestion
```

Application view creates and stores a collection of special items. At a certain time the first and the second subview needs to get access to that collection. Now what is the best way to pass the collection it to them?

I myself see some ways, yet each has a downside:

1) Create instance of that collection not inside the App View but even more globally and then pass it around as dependency (project uses RequireJS; so it would be passed to AppView and both Subviews).
Downsides: app view is supposed to be the top most element in application. Yet suddenly we have some instances of collections floating above.

2) Or I can do following:

```
// some subview
var collection = {};
Backbone.trigger( "item:getSpecialItems", collection);
// now the collection has data

// app view
this.listenTo( "item:getSpecialItems", function(obj) {
    // copy collection to passed object
    _.extend(obj, this.specialCollection);
});
```

Downsides: we are triggering a global event. We know that only the app view would respond, but it feels like a bad design. Plus, this way to pass the collection seems like a hack.

Maybe there are some other clever ways to do it?

Comment: When you say "Collection" do you mean a Backbone.Collection?  Because your sample code has `var collection = {};` (which certainly *isn't* a Backbone Collection)?

Comment: In my case it is Backbone.Collection but I it doesn't really matter as we would have the same issue if we wanted to pass plain object or array. Using extend I believe we at the very least would copy array of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say #1.

> app view is supposed to be the top most element in application

Right, but you're talking about (I *think*) a `Collection`, not a `View`; the two are totally separate parts of your application (in MVC the first is the "M" and the second is the "V").  By definition, if your views are driven by your data, the data *must* be "higher" (in the dependency tree) than any view, so I don't see anything wrong with that approach.

Comment: I have different kinds of views. Some make no sense without model being passed to them (say ToDo row without the model) but some create model themselves and then display it once data is received. So they have their own template and only part of it updates when data come in. In my case App View doesn't even care about that collection. It's just common parent for both SubViews so I moved initialization of collection there. Got your point, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get a shared instance of the collection, my approach would be to pass that down from the parent to "subview" and from subview into its children.  However, I wouldn't necessarily use require to pass around a singleton of this collection.

You could also pull out all of the logic from the view regarding the special methods for "creation and storage of special objects" into a helper class whose sole domain is just this.  That helper then becomes a utility available from outside the view hierarchy, ***perhaps*** even globally or via require.

Comment: Passing it down is very logical and something I would do right away if subviews would be direct children of the view with the collection. And  here we have several subviews which know nothing about this collection but somehow should pass it down the tree. Your second options is basically my first one but with a wrapper which would hold all global data/objects/collections which may appear in the future?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure based on your description whether that "manager" is just a collection or has additional 'stuff' specific to that.  Imagine you have a collection of users or something that you use from everywhere, you'd create a "UserHelper" which exposes a nicer or more concise API on that collection, or the collection becomes implementation details abstracted from the consumer.  I wasn't really gunning for a manager that holds multiple dependencies at the global scope.

Comment: If you are interested I have realized that I already have global objects which are needed in different parts. They include configs (with url to the services), locales (with text to use in certain messages). So I've though that it would be a good idea to wrap them together with that global collection and call everything AppData or something. Now each view may require it if needed.